# GLSL Shaders do not compile even if they have no obvious bugs

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been trying to texture a cube I have created and I am not able to see the textures. I can just see a blank cube rendering. I have tried not using a texture and making it a single color but that hasn’t worked either. I have looked at the code to see if there is anything wrong with it however I don't see any problems but I think it is because I am new to OpenGL so maybe someone else can see what is wrong with the code.

This is my texture code within vertex_array constructor:

```
vertex_array::vertex_array(float* vertex_buffer, int num_of_floats, const std::string& texture_file)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &va_ID);
    glBindVertexArray(va_ID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vb_ID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb_ID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, num_of_floats * sizeof(float), vertex_buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(0 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int width, height, nrChanells;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(texture_file.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChanells, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else {std::cout << "failed to load texture" << std::endl;}
    stbi_image_free(data);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ib_ID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib_ID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(index_buffer), index_buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

This is my shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
v_TexCoord = texCoord;
gl_Position = projection * view * position;
};

#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

void main()
{
vec4 texColor = texture(u_Texture, v_TexCoord);
color = texColor;
//color = vec4(0.0, 0.7, 0.4, 1.0);
};
```

This is the shader class:

```
#include "shader.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

shader::shader(const std::string& shader_file)
{
    std::ifstream file(shader_file);
    std::string line;
    std::stringstream shaders[2];
    std::string shader_type;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        if (line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos)
        {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
                shader_type = "vertex";
            else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
                shader_type = "fragment";
        }

        else
        {
            if (shader_type == "vertex")
            {
                shaders[0] << line << "\n";
                //std::cout << line << "\n";
            }
            else if (shader_type == "fragment")
            {
                shaders[1] << line << "\n";
                //std::cout << line << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    s_ID = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs_ID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    unsigned int fs_ID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char* vertex_shader = shaders[0].str().c_str();
    const char* fragment_shader = shaders[1].str().c_str(); 
    glShaderSource(vs_ID, 1, &vertex_shader, nullptr);
    glShaderSource(fs_ID, 1, &fragment_shader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vs_ID);
    glCompileShader(fs_ID);
    glAttachShader(s_ID, vs_ID);
    glAttachShader(s_ID, fs_ID);
    glLinkProgram(s_ID);
    glValidateProgram(s_ID);
    glDeleteShader(vs_ID);
    glDeleteShader(fs_ID);
}

void shader::bind()
{
    glUseProgram(s_ID);
}

void shader::unbind()
{
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

and is my main application code:

```
vertex_array va_1(cube1, 40, "resources/blocks.png");
shader shader_1("src/shader1.shader");
va_1.bind();
shader_1.bind();
```

**[Edit by Spektre]**

after peaking into **GLSL** shader logs the problem is:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: illegal extended ASCII character (0xdd)
```

which means wrong encoding somwhere along the way

Comment: It seems the shader program is not used. Did you Forget to install the shader program before drawing the geometry ([`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml))?  Anyway this example is not [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which is the value of `nrChanells`? It affects `GL_RGB` or `GL_RGBA` parameters to `glTexImage2D`

Comment: sorry Ripi2 I didnt fully understand what you said however I can see it has to do with the textures but I tried doing it without textures and it still output a single colour so there is a problem that isnt to do with the textures however that doesnt mean there isnt a problem with the textures aswell so could you clarify what you meant

Comment: Rabbid76 yes the shader is used because I call shader_1.bind() in the main file which calls glUseProgram()

Comment: I will edit so the shader class is included

Comment: Some image formats (e.g. .jpg) don't have transparency. Others (e.g. .png) do. In this last case `nrChanells=4`  and you must use `GL_RGBA`

Comment: Ok so if nrChanells is 4 then surely stbi will set it to 4 for me? and thanks ill change it to GL_RGBA but why must it be this?

Comment: @Spektre thanks for the advice, to answer some of you questions, I do have texture coordinates, I see a blank cube with no texture or colour, and I do have two shaders a vertex and fragment which I attach both to one program and shader.bind() binds the program, I don't do much error checking for things like if the shaders compile and link or checking GLSL logs only because currently I have a very small program that is easy to read through so I didnt think that was neccesary however I think I will just do that anyway to see if it helps

Comment: @Spektre also after countlessly checking my code i decided to try directly copying some other opengl code from learnopengl that was supposed to show rotating cubes which I did to see if it ran as expected and it just output a blank square so I think there could be something else going on aswell other than errors in my code yet im not quite sure what

Comment: Ok thanks so I what I will once I get home is try now is to implement GLSL logs so that they can tell me  if the problem is my IDE is using UNICODE or if it is something else.

Comment: @spektre so I tried adding the GLSL logs and I found this error: ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: illegal extended ASCII character (0xdd), so I think it is a problem with using unicode and previously you said to enforce ASCII but how would I do this?

Comment: @Spektre Sorry I am struggling to understand what you mean exactly. So I need to edit my shader files with non unicode tools which by that do you mean not to use unicode characters when writing my shader? Also by loading my shaders as bytes do you mean read the file directly into chars rather than into strings? If this is what you meant, you said to use some macro however could you give an example of how to use this macro because I can not see very well how it would be used from what you said. Should I create a new question now that I better understand the problem so you can answer over there?

Comment: @AmeenIzhac weird I did not got notified ... 1. Yes you got it edit the shader files in some text editor like notepad or what ever with non unicode configuration. You can also write a small program that reads the file and check if all its BYTEs are valid ASCII so `<128` I know there are also some character sin extended ASCII (above 127) but those are usually not used in programming (or should not be).  2. BYTE is  8 bit data type (unsigned char) you can use chars instead but be sure your chars are chars and not unicode wide chars !!! may be better whould be use something like `unsigned __int8`

Comment: @AmeenIzhac 3. no I can not show you macro example different than `TEXT( )` (which I saw to use in other QAs here) as I do not use them I am stuck on non unicode tools due to my work so I do not need them. 4. new question is up to you ...but I would edit this one and notify others of update. Maybe also clear obsolete  comments and move the relevant data to your question instead as right now the comments are a mess to read.  5. MCVE now when you know more you should verify it with small shader code like simple fragment `out vec4 color; void main(){ color=vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);  }` 
  `

Comment: @AmeenIzhac and include the GLSL logs ... do not forget to change the title too so it matches the problem...

Comment: @AmeenIzhac I moved the coments into answer and deleted the obsolete ones ... You should do the same and edit your question to match your new knowledge of the problem. May be notify Rabbid and Ripi as they got a lot of experience with GL/GLSL (we meet on similar questions quite often) beware you can notify only one user per comment

Comment: It seems your shader-loading code expects lines like `#shader vertex`, but I don't see those lines in your shader file. Have you checked that the strings passed to `glShaderSource` have the expected content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No colors can mean problem with lighting/normal or just not compiled/linked shaders resulting in usage of fixed function which uses the input locations differently hence no color/texture etc.

First of all check **GLSL** logs as it is absolutely necessary. Even a small bug like missing `;` or wrong character might prevent you from compiling and without checking you just do not know what works or not. Take a look here:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

  And look how `glGetShaderInfoLog` and `glGetProgramInfoLog` are used. Save or print their results to check for errors.

After you done this it Looks like you got problem with encoding of the shaders:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: illegal extended ASCII character (0xdd)
```

There are more reasons what could cause this:

1. **error in shader file**

   If you edit your shader with UNICODE tools or using national keyboard or copy paste from WEB the resulting file might contain "special" characters or even the whole file could be encoded as UNICODE (**UTF8,UTF16**). That is wrong as gfx driver **GLSL** compiler can not handle such.

   So check the files in hex view (or write a small script that check for presence of non ASCII codes above `127`).

   the **UTF** encoding is easy to detect here is a hex view of **UTF8** SVG file start:

   ```
   EF BB BF 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E | ď»ż<?xml version
   ```

   Here another SVG but **UTF16** this time:

   ```
   FF FE 3C 00 3F 00 78 00 6D 00 6C 00 20 00 76 00 | ˙ţ< ? x m l   v
   ```

   As you can see the starting 2 BYTEs are the **UTF** magic number detecting the **UTF** encoding. In **UTF8** character can be 1 or more bytes. In **UTF16** each character has 2 bytes. This is easily detectable. But if your file has just non **ASCII** character (`code>127`) it can be very hard to spot and writing a script that detects it would be more reliable.

   However the error message suggest your problems are in first line so you do not need to search whole file to spot it... If you use **Total Commander** hit `[F3]` on your shader file and then hit `[3]` to see hex view or use any other hex view tool at your disposal.
2. **error in loading the file into your program**

   I do not know which compiler/IDE/platform you got but If your compiler is UNICODE friendly its possible you are loading your shader file into some string variable that is enforcing UNICODE. In such case you will not found any bug in the **#1** but compiler still throws illegal character.

   To confirm this after you load your shader into your string save it back to some file and check if its encoding is OK (do **#1** on it).

   If the case simply stop using the string variable that do this and use array of 8 bit data types instead. Beware if you want to use `char` you must be sure it is char and not UNICODE Wide char instead !!! Do not ask me how search the documentation to your compiler/IDE instead.

   Once this is resolved (saved file is standard **ASCII** text) the **GLSL** compilation should proceed without errors...
3. **enforcing ASCII and shader code inside cpp code**

   Some programs do not use shader files. Instead they store the source code as const strings in the app source code. This way is susceptible to the same problems as **#2**. To resolve this some compilers introduce a macro that tells the compiler that string is a ASCII and not UNICODE and should handle it as such. I do not know how the macros are named but I saw use them here on SE/SO in different GLSL related questions. IIRC it was something like:

   ```
   const char *txt=TEXT('bla bla vla');
   ```

   but I am not sure if it was really just `TEXT` or `Text` or something slightly different. So search the **QA**s for your error code or enforcing **ASCII** or look into your compiler/IDE documentation for such things.

Also common rookie problem is that they build entire application and only than start to compile. THAT IS WRONG. Because after that they spend eternity debugging...

They should build apps incrementally. So start small and when working move to next step. This way if a bug reveals itself its 99% time in the just added new code hence no need to difficult searching ...

The new GL api however prevents from this approach as you need to have valid GL context, VBO/VAO, mesh loader/generator, view, shaders, compatible gfx driver before the stuff even start showing something. That is a huge amount of possible problems at once. That is why I advice to start with old api and then removing part by part with the new one ... Or use some working start template instead.

Comment: 1. so from your first point I understood that your concern is that my shader code contains non ASCII characters and you suggested making a program that checks for non ASCII characters so I made a C++ program that casts each character of a string to an int and outputs it if its value is bigger than 126 and when inputing the entire shadercode, there was no output so I assume thats not the issue.

Comment: 2. Surely if the string is enforcing UNICODE on ASCII characters that is not a problem because im pretty sure the first 128 characters of UNICODE are the same as the ASCII characters so enforcing UNICODE on already checked to be ASCII characters should just leave the coding the same shouldn’t it. Also, after reading in the file to the string, I printed the string and it printed like normal.

Comment: 3. If I cannot manage to read in the shader from the file I will probably use string and macro.

Comment: @AmeenIzhac your **#2** assumption is wrong as enforced UNICODE like UTF16 is not the same as ASCII as there will be a lot of zeros along the ASCII which will lead to wrong compilation after first character of code ...

Comment: Ok so I opened the file in notepad++, went to encoding, I found it was set on encode in UTF8, I selected convert to ANSI saved it, then reopened it and it is still on UTF8 no matter how many times I repeat that

Comment: I decided to store my source for shaders as const strings in the main app source code and I now dont see any errors reported from the shader however I now see nothing at all on the screen when I run it (apart from the background colour). Currently this is what I am looking into.